# Full Screen: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on Windows 10 Hyper-V

Tags: 14.04, display-resolution, windows-10, fullscreen, virtualization

I got Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running as a VM on my Alienware laptop running Windows 10. Everything looks good so far except for the fact that when I put the VM connection window into "full screen" view, the Ubuntu desktop still only occupies a small rectangle in the middle of the screen.

Under All Settings->Displays I see the resolution is set to "1162x864 4:3", but that doesn't seem to be the case.

How can I get it to full screen?

Thank you!

Take care,
Scott

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2014/09/19/changing-ubuntu-screen-resolution-in-a-hyper-v-vm/) you must do the following:

> 1. Open Terminal
> 2. Type: sudo vi /etc/default/grub
> 3. Find the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, and add video=hyperv_fb:[the resolution you want].  The resolution I want is
>      1280x720.  So my line ends up looking like this:
>      GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1280x720"
> 4. Write the changes and quit vi.
> 5. Run: sudo update-grub
> 6. Reboot the virtual machine